# Created image element is not placed at the correct location inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, createelement

I have an HTML that has a few div elements for example like this:

```
<body id="theBody">

  <div id="box1">
    <div id="boxLeft"></div>
    <div id="boxRight"></div>
  </div>
  ...
```

In the JavaScript code I do something like this:

```
var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("boxLeft");

newImg = document.createElement("img");
newImg.src = "image1.png";
topPos = 200;
leftPos = 200;
newImg.style.top = topPos + "px"; 
newImg.style.left = leftPos + "px"; 
newImg.setAttribute("width",  "60px");
theLeftSide.appendChild(newImg);
```

I expect that the image is shown at the correct location of (200, 200) inside the `boxLeft`, but instead it is shown on the top left corner of the page.

What am I doing wrong here?

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: try setting the position to relative

Comment: Can you please elaborate, I am beginner in JavaScript.

Comment: `newImg.style.position= "relative";`

Comment: In short, your question is about CSS, not JavaScript (which is working as excpected).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply absolute positioning to the image.

```
#boxLeft img {
    position: absolute;
}
```

or `newImg.style.position= "absolute";`

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pkjte9tg/2/)**

Comment: In the CSS I have: div {
  position: absolute;
  top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
} I need the div position to be absolute.

Comment: You're applying absolute positioning for every div element in the page?

Comment: Yes, I am applying absolute positioning for every div.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this css:

```
#boxLeft{
    position: relative;
}

img{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course, but he does not have a class or an id for the image.